# Can animals spawn?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

The new release of Minecraft: PE features baby animals. Will these animals eventually spawn in existing worlds, or will my kids (who have built some rather elaborate structures for the Pocket Edition) have to start over?

It appears to be the case that animals never spawn in older versions of PE; are the baby animals a change to that, or are they just a new thing which could be running around at the beginning of a game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If their Minecraft PE is 1.6.1 or later, I am 100 percent sure that your kids will just have to wait a bit. (About a month in Minecraft days) and if there are few enough remaining animals, new ones will spawn. Eventually. Some of the new spawns will be babies.  This unfortunately will wear off in time though.

I know this because I spent hours fencing all the animals in my world.  No more spawned for about 3 (real) months. My brother joined on multiplayer and immediately proceeded to kill all my sheep. I was very angry. After a while I went outside and was logging, when I actually saw a baby sheep spawn out of nowhere. Then a cow and a pig. Then a baby chicken. Etc. I checked this on every site I could find on this topic. 8 out of ten said the same thing.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your kids would have to start over in a new world in order to get the baby animals.

According to the update changelog on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history#0.6.0), baby animals only will spawn in new worlds, in the same fashion as adult animals spawn.

Answer (score 1):

I had a game that was made before I updated, then while I was playing it, I found a cute little baby sheep racing around near my house!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't explored the entire area yet, the chunks wouldn't have been generated in that area, so it's possible to find baby animals. If you explored the whole seed, then you will have to make a new save and make sure you don't explore everywhere at once, because something might be added in a few updates that will be really superior and that thing might spawn into your unexplored chunks.Therefore, it is possible to do this, only if you have not explored the entire area in which the new items could spawn it. Ask your kids if they explored the entire area or not.

Comment: This only applies to the PC edition, see @icyslurpee 's answer

Comment: It also works with the Ipad also, I saw babies on the Ipad version and I haven't looked at some places and saw baby piglets.